# Use Selection Field in Another Model in Odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo

I'm totally a newbie here who love Odoo so much :)

I got stuck with this problem for a few days in Odoo CE 13.

I want my SHIPPING TYPE field which I made in ***sale.order*** can be used in ***purchase.order*** as well.

So I did this in ***shipping_type.py***

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from odoo import models, fields
    
    class SaleOrder(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'sale.order'
    
        shipping_selection = [
                    ('type1', 'Instant'),
                    ('type2', 'Same Day'),
                    ('type3', 'JNE'),
                    ('type4', 'Tokopedia'),
                    ('type5', 'Pick Up'),
                    ('type6', 'AnterAja-Reguler'),
                    ('type7', 'J&T-Reguler'),
                    ('type8', 'Ninja-Reguler'),
    
                     ]
    
        shipping_type = fields.Selection(shipping_selection,'Shipping Type',)
```

Then, I was trying to make ***purchase_shipping_type.py*** in another addons, and created this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields

class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['sale.order']

    shipping_selection = [
                ('type1', 'Instant'),
                ('type2', 'Same Day'),
                ('type3', 'JNE'),
                ('type4', 'Tokopedia'),
                ('type5', 'Pick Up'),
                ('type6', 'AnterAja-Reguler'),
                ('type7', 'J&T-Reguler'),
                ('type8', 'Ninja-Reguler'),

                 ]

    shipping_type = fields.Selection(shipping_selection,'Shipping Type',)

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['purchase.order']

   shipping_type_purchase = fields.Selection(string='Shipping Type',related=shipping_type.shipping_type_purhase, readonly=True)
```

This error showed up:

```
Aug 21 06:29:03 kama-odoo-server odoo13[24202]: NameError: name 'shipping_type' is not defined - - -
```

How to set up this properly? I really hope someone can help me :) Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @fransiskus Felix You need to make the shipping_selection like global variable in your python file.

Answer (score 3):

The related attribute is used to specify a sequence of field names.

> The value of a related field is given by following a sequence of relational fields and reading a field on the reached model. The complete sequence of fields to traverse is specified by the related attribute.

When using [Selction](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/fields.py#L2120) fields, The attribute `selection` is mandatory except in the case of [related](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields) or [extended](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/fields.py#L2109) fields.

You can find a related selection field in [account](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/models/account.py#L84) model which is declared as following:

```py
user_type_id = fields.Many2one('account.account.type', ...)
internal_type = fields.Selection(related='user_type_id.type', ...)
```

You can find also a selection field in account partner which uses a [constant list](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/models/partner.py#L427) declared in base `res_partner` model:

```py
from odoo.addons.base.models.res_partner import WARNING_MESSAGE, WARNING_HELP

invoice_warn = fields.Selection(WARNING_MESSAGE, 'Invoice', help=WARNING_HELP, default="no-message")
```

To keep the declaration of the `shipping_selection` in `SaleOrder` class, you need to remove `related` attribute and modify the `shipping_type_purchase` field as followin:

```py
shipping_type_purchase = fields.Selection(shipping_selection, ...)
```

If `SaleOrder` class is not declared in the same module, you have just to import it like in the example above.

You can decalre the `shipping_selection` as a constant list then modify the `shipping_type_purchase` field:

```py
SHIPPING_SELECTION = [
        ('type1', 'Instant'),
        ('type2', 'Same Day'),
        ('type3', 'JNE'),
        ('type4', 'Tokopedia'),
        ('type5', 'Pick Up'),
        ('type6', 'AnterAja-Reguler'),
        ('type7', 'J&T-Reguler'),
        ('type8', 'Ninja-Reguler'),

    ]

class SaleOrder(models.Model):

    shipping_type = fields.Selection(SHIPPING_SELECTION, ...)


class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    
    shipping_type_purchase = fields.Selection(SHIPPING_SELECTION, ...)
```

Comment: Hi Kenly, I apologize for the late response. This one looks good. Somehow my team changed how it works. But, we will have similar cases soon, will definitely try it & let you know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `shipping_type` in `PurchaseOrder` with `SaleOrder.shipping_type` and it should do it.

The reason is that `shipping_type` is defined as part of a class and should be referenced as such

[EDIT]: In this particular case though you have a relation between your models and it should be handled with a one2many or many2one field (see [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#relational-fields))

Comment: Hi qmeeus, thank you for your answer :)

I tried it as you suggested:

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
 _inherit = ['purchase.order']

       shipping_type_purchase = fields.Selection(string='Shipping Type', 
       related=SaleOrder.shipping_type.shipping_type_purchase, readonly=True)

It gave me this error:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object - - -

Comment: My bad, you have to build relational models. I am not an expert with Odoo but I added a link in my answer that can point you in the right direction